# Flutter: Method not found: ButtonTheme.bar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

I was working on this project for past 4-5 months and after the flutter 2.0 update it started producing plugin version conflicts between `flutter_form_builder` and `intl`.

After downgrading `flutter_form_builder` to `3.14.1` I had this error related to `date_range_picker`,

```
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/date_range_picker-1.0.6/lib/date_range_picker.dart:1152:44: Error: Method not found: 'ButtonTheme.bar'.
    final Widget actions = new ButtonTheme.bar(
```

After fixing it with `overriding dependency` using this code

```
date_range_picker:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/LempereurBenjamin/date_range_picker
```

I got this error

```
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/country_pickers-1.3.0/lib/utils/my_alert_dialog.dart:139:36: Error: Method not found: 'ButtonTheme.bar'.
      children.add(new ButtonTheme.bar(                                 
                                   ^^^
```

Note: I'm not using any of these plugins i.e, `date_range_picker` or `country_pickers`

Comment: Do you have the correct import? I cannot find `ButtonTheme.bar` either. When using ButtonTheme, my class is pulling from the `material` package.

Comment: The problem is, I'm not using `ButtonTheme.bar` anywhere in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After messing around with this weird error, I found a solution.

**Error caused by `country_pickers`**

I didn't use `country_pickers` in my project and what caused this error was the usage of `country_pickers` version `1.3.0` by one of the package I was using, which threw this exception,

```
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/country_pickers-1.3.0/lib/utils/my_alert_dialog.dart:139:36: Error: Method not found: 'ButtonTheme.bar'.
      children.add(new ButtonTheme.bar(                                 
                                   ^^^
```

All I needed to do was to override my project's dependency on `country_pickers` to version `2.0.0`

```
dependency_overrides:
  country_pickers: ^2.0.0
```

**Error caused by `date_range_picker`**

If you face the following error,

```
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/date_range_picker-1.0.6/lib/date_range_picker.dart:1152:44: Error: Method not found: 'ButtonTheme.bar'.
    final Widget actions = new ButtonTheme.bar(
```

Override `date_range_picker` dependency,

```
date_range_picker:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/LempereurBenjamin/date_range_picker
```

P.S: You might get these errors even if you are not using any of these packages, because some package you are using might depend on any of these.

Answer (score 0):

I think `ButtonTheme.bar` is deprecated in Flutter 2.0 instead use `ButtonBarTheme`. Try this may it will work.

[Improvement](https://github.com/artrmz/watermaniac/issues/3)- Refer this it is an improvement.

Comment: The problem is, I'm not using `ButtonTheme.bar` anywhere in my code.